# Counting semaphores initialized to n

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, operating-system, semaphore, locks

If a counting semaphore is initialized to n, does it mean n processes can run their critical sections concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes.

Remember a counting semaphore will only block when the count is negative after decrementing. Therefore, the semaphore can be decremented n times before blocking. Since all decrements must be matched with an increment, then, assuming each process decrements the semaphore only once (which is, by far, the most common case), then yes, n processes will be able to run their critical sections at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the very purpose of semaphores? Mutual Exclusion? or are counting semaphores always supposed to be initialized to 1?

Comment: The purpose of a semaphore is to allow n-number of acquisitions, so by definition, no it doesn't defeat the purpose.  If you wanted a mutex-semaphore then, yes it would - in that case define a semaphore(1).  `or are counting semaphores always supposed to be initialized to 1?` only if you need mutual exclusion

Answer (score 1):

No.

If n > 0, then it means that the counting semaphore can be taken exactly n times before the requesting context blocks and waits for the counting semaphore to become available (assuming no one gives it during that period).

If n <= 0, then it means that that counting semaphore must be given (1 - n) times before anyone can successfully take that counting semaphore.

Controlling access to a critical section is typically better handled by a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have initialized semaphore to N, then sem_wait will not block any thread unless it has already been called N times, then only semaphore becomes -ve and that's when any thread calling sem_wait blocks.

for critical section you have to use binary semaphores or mutex.